# Liferay 6.2, Amazon S3 TLS version problem, Invalid Bucket: null

Tags: amazon-s3, tls1.2, liferay-6

Till amazon stopped supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections our DLFile methods were working fine while adding/deleting files. After the update we started to receive  *com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: The action Create Object in bucket cannot be performed with an invalid bucket: null*

and

*org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException:S3 Error Message. -- Response Code: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">`InvalidTlsVersion`Amazon S3 will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections....*

I've updated the tomcat server.xml file as follows ;

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="keyStorePath"
       keystorePass="keyStorePass" clientAuth="false"
       sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
       ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
       compression="on" compressionMinSize="1024"
       noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/javascript,text/css,application/json,text/javascript,text/plain,application/octet-stream,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/x-icon"/>
```

and still getting *com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: The action Create Object in bucket cannot be performed with an invalid bucket: null* error. Sometimes it just works and sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: Tomcat `server.xml` only controls connections TO Tomcat from clients such as browsers i.e. where _Tomcat is the server_ (hence the filename); it has absolutely nothing to do with connections to something else or somewhere else FROM code you supply. You need to identify and look at, and possibly ask about, the code that is making the connection that is being rejected.